# Nested Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, magnific-popup

I want to pass from one magnific-popup item to an another one, perform some action and then go back to the first one.
To achieve this, I override the close method (before openning the second element) with $.magnificPopup.instance.close in which I call $.magnificPopup.proto.open() method. This seems to work, but I can not override it back to its initial behavior and the close button of the first popup still triggers the modified behavior. Here is a corresponding jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/matthieuG/ddkc83ca/12/

```
$('.first-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    closeBtnInside:true,
    callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      /*var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance;*/
    },
    open: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
        console.log('close override is working');
        $.magnificPopup.proto.open({
          callbacks:{
            open: function() {
              console.log('open callback');
              $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
                $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
                console.log('open close callback');
              }
            }
          },
          items: {
            src: '#first-popup' 
          },
          type: 'inline'         
        });     
      }
    }
  }
 });

$('.second-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    closeBtnInside:true,
    closeOnBgClick: false,
    callbacks: {
    beforeOpen: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
        $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
        console.log('2nd close override is not working');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: your fiddle has trouble with syntax, correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have to close the first instance of the magnific popup.
This post helped me to find out a working solution: http://www.4byte.cn/question/173750/callbacks-not-firing-when-opening-a-magnific-popup-from-another-one.html

My working solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/matthieuG/zt4coq8f/1/

```
$('.first-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',
  closeBtnInside: true,
  closeOnBgClick: false,
  closeOnContentClick: false,
  callbacks: {
    beforeOpen: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
      $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
      };
      // $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
      console.log('before open has been initiated');
    }
  }
});

$('.second-popup-link').click(function() {
  $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
});

$('.second-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',
  closeBtnInside: true,
  closeOnBgClick: false,
  closeOnContentClick: false,
  callbacks: {
    beforeOpen: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
        $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
        $('.first-popup-link').trigger('click');

      };
      // $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
      console.log('before open has been initiated');
    },
      close: function() {
      console.log('Popup 2 close has been initiated');

    }
  }
});
```